# Going from a PreferenceScreen to a DialogPreference

Tags: android

My application has a setting menu which is actually a PreferenceActivity. 
When it's created, if a boolean value is not set I want to go to the DialogPreference which sets that.

I tried doing it with an intent but the application force closed with this error msg:

> E/AndroidRuntime(  239):
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
>   Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {com.xxxx/com.xxxx.xxxxPreference};
>   have you declared this activity in
>   your AndroidManifest.xml?

How should I do this? It's ok to add that DialogPreference to the manifest?

Comment: force closed mean an uncatched exception has been throwed. Have a look at the LogCat.

Comment: You are right, I just add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `DialogPreference` isn't an `Activity` in its own right.  It's just a `Preference` which displays a `Dialog` when clicked.

The problem is that there's no obvious way programmatically click a `Preference`.  However, since you're using `DialogPreference` you've already got you own subclass of it.  So we can solve our problem by adding the following method to your subclass of `DialogPreference`:

```
//Expose the protected onClick method
void show() {
    onClick();
}
```

Then in the `onCreate()` of your `PreferencesActivity` you'll have something like this to load the preferences from your XML file:

```
// Load the preferences from an XML resource
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

After that you can put some code like this:

```
booleanProp = true; //set this to the value of the property you're checking     

if (! booleanProp) {
    //Find the Preference via its android:key
    //MyDialogPreference is your subclasss of DialogPreference
    MyDialogPreference dp = (MyDialogPreference)getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("dialog_preference");  
    dp.show();
}
```

This is a bit of hack, as exposing `protected` methods isn't ideal, but it does work.

Another option would be to replace the `Dialog` with a `PrefenceActivity` which contained all the options you wish to maintain and then you could launch it via an `Intent`, but I'm assuming there's a good reason that you want your own custom `Dialog` with a specific layout.  If you do want a second `PreferenceActivity` you can add it to your preferences XML file as follows:

```
<PreferenceScreen
        android:title="@string/title_of_preference"
        android:summary="@string/summary_of_preference">
    <intent android:action="your.action.goes.HERE"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Dave, excellent answer. But I missing how to instantiate it since I need the attrs that are in the pref.xml

Comment: @Macarse - Doesn't the call to `addPreferencesFromResource` instantiate the `DialogPreference` with everything it needs?  If yo put my code after that it should be OK.  (Have edited the answer to clarify this.)

Answer (score -1):

To start an activity with an Intent, the activity must be in the Android manifest.  Just add a line like:

```
<activity android:name=".path.to.MyActivity"/>
```

Comment: I get an error. xxxxPreference does not extend android.app.Activity.

Comment: Is xxxPreference a Dialog, not an activity?  To show a dialog you use dialog.show(), Intents are meant to kick of activities.  If you want an activity that looks like a Dialog, you can set the theme of your activity to be Theme.Dialog.

Comment: it's a Dialog but to do a .show() I must instantiate it and I need the attrs that are in the pref.xml :(