# DialogPreference constructor sets onPreferenceClickListener?

Tags: android, dialog-preference

I have set an `onPreferenceClickListener` on my subclass of `DialogPreference` like so:

```
public class SeekBarDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {
    ...
    public void show() {
        onClick();
    }
}


public class TopPage extends PreferenceActivity {
    ...
    SeekBarDialogPreference Foo = (SeekBarDialogPreference) findPreference("Foo");
    foo.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference pref) {
            ((SeekBarDialogPreference) pref).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

When the `SeekBarDialogPreference` is clicked, `showDialog()` and `onCreateDialogView(`) are called twice each. My question is does the `DialogPreference` constructor generate a click listener by default, making my code redundant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. Publicizing `onClick()` is redundant. This leads me to question the credibility of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2177490/1210260).